# Can Seeming disguise a mummy as a specific human? (D&D 5E)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

Background for the question: in my campaign, I have a Mummy being controlled by a group that includes an Illusionist.  I need to make the Mummy appear as if he is a certain human NPC.  I know I could use True Polymorph, but I don't want to have to have to make the controlling Illusionist that high of a level.

My question:  Would the 5th level spell *Seeming* accomplish what I am trying to do?  I do not need the Mummy to speak or really do anything other than sit there and look like a human.  The text for the spell says that it changes the targets appearance; would this be adequate or would I need to use True Polymorph?